# Changing Position of DIV on Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, scroll

I have a table

```
<table>
<tr> <td> ---- asp.net gridview </td>
<td> <div class=persondetails> </div> </td></tr>
</table>
```

My javascript got from another forum article

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var personDetail = document.querySelector('.persondetails');
        alert (personDetail);
        var origOffsetY = personDetail.offsetTop;
        debugger;
        function onScroll(e) {
            debugger;
            window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? personDetail.classList.add('sticky') :
                                            personDetail.classList.remove('sticky');
        }

        document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    </script>
```

My asp.net gridview grows vertically depending on the no. of persons.  When a person on the grid is selected, the div on the second td is populated with some fields.  It works fine.

When the list grows too large, and I have to select a person at the bottom, the person details on the right side is shown at the top. This makes users to scroll up to see the details of the person selected in the grid at the bottom of the page.

Is there a way to show the div on the right side td to scroll down when users scroll down the page?  I checked other links on this forum but didn't work out.  I'm not sure if this due to my table and td layout.

I get null at the alert specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `position fixed` like this:

```
var $details = $(".details"),
    detailsPos = $details.position().top;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > detailsPos)
        $details.css("position", "fixed").css("top",0);
    else
        $details.css("position", "static");
});
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/vvr8nvt6/)

Note that the code should be wrapped in `document ready` like this:

```
$(function() {
    // ... code ...
});
```

Also check [`position fixed` compatibility here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed)

Comment: it gives error "Object expected" at var $details = $(".personDetail");

Comment: What browser are you using? Try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/paska/vvr8nvt6/1/

Comment: I got an exception on IE8.  I understand that is not supported with jquery. I have tried in Firefox.  It doesn't give error but it doesn't work there too.

Comment: The second version I made is supposed to work on IE8. I'm using Firefox and it does work. Do you have a ver old version?

Comment: In Chrome, uncaught type error: cannot read property 'top' of undefined. in Fiefox also, I don't see the error but I kept alert on detailspos but it si not coming up. I used Firefox 41.0.1. and Chrome 45.0.2454.101.

Comment: Does that happen when you run the fiddle or when you try to use the code in your scenario?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92432/discussion-between-user2169261-and-diego).

Comment: no, i'm still facing issues with IE8. Firefox and Chrome work good

Comment: If you are using the right version of jQuery (1.X) then this code should work in IE8

Comment: I use jquery-2.1.3.min.js

Comment: I added this to work on IE8 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

Comment: You can change directly to version 1.11.3 instead of the conditional script. I don't think it would make you any difference, and even if it does you will see it easily and be able to change it and maintain one only code. I use v1.X a lot.

Comment: It looks like I lose my previous css settings when I use $details.css("position", "fixed").css("top", 0); Is there a way to retain my old values and just apply top 0? For example, I kept a button on the right side, but after applying this logic, when I scroll down, my button show up but appears on the left.

Comment: You need to adapt your styles to the position fixed. It works different. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to use CSS styled divs.

- You may set your right div to always show on scrolling e.g. sticky divs or
- You may wrap your grid view in a div with fixed height so that your left table scrolls in that div within the view port.